# What is the purpose of wrapping this private deleter function in a struct?

Tags: c++

I've been trying to understand an [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/181600/343855) to a different question and for the most part I think I do. However, what is the purpose of wrapping the private `deleter_fn` in a `struct`?

For convenience, here is the code I'm looking at:

```
class C {
public:
  void foo() {
    underlying_foo(handle.get());
  }

  void bar() {
    // transfers ownership
    underlying_bar(handle.release());
  }

  // use default copy/move constructor and assignment operator

private:
  struct deleter {
    void operator()(T* ptr) {
      deleter_fn(ptr);
    }
  };
  std::unique_ptr<T, deleter> handle;
};
```

Why not just:

```
...
private:

    void operator()(T* ptr) {
      deleter_fn(ptr);
    }
  std::unique_ptr<T, deleter> handle;
};
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, your second version should be without operator and passing directly deleter_fn to unique_ptr template.

Comment: Ah of course - a typo - `deleter` should be `deleter_fn` in the second version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your version there is no `deleter` so `std::unique_ptr<T, deleter> handle` doesn't make sense. You would need to write `std::unique_ptr<T, C> handle;` (because your `operator()` is a member of `C`). The problem with this is that `C` is not empty and stateful. If the deleter of `std::unique_ptr` is an empty class then it can do some optimizations and not actually store the deleter object. Otherwise it has to accommodate extra space for the deleter, which is unnecessary in your case.